# Ruby is adding weird spacing between words

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My website is printing out elements such as (SnO), however, it should be printing SnO, but it is adding a weird space and it is printing like Sn O. It is adding a space between the element for no reason. My code is on the listed below.

```
<% saved_element = ""%>
<% sensor.base_material.elests.each_with_index do |elest, v| %>
        <% if elest.element.include? "O" %> 
            <% saved_element = elest %>
        <% else %>
            <%=elest.element.split('-').last %>
            <% if elest.stoich != 1 %>
                <sub><%=elest.stoich.to_i%></sub>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
        <% if v == sensor.base_material.elests.length-1 %>
            <%=saved_element.element.split('-').last%>
            <% if saved_element.stoich != 1 %>
                <sub><%=saved_element.stoich.to_i %></sub>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What do you see in the HTML when you inspect the text? What does the resulting element look like?

Comment: A compounding factor here is that you're doing a bunch of logic in your view that you should be doing in your controller. Move as much of this code as possible to your controller and pass to your view only the values you actually want to render. If the problem then still exists, it will be much easier to debug.

Comment: I agree with @JordanRunning that it doesn't belong in the view. But the controller might not be the right place either. This looks like something that belongs in the model or a helper.

Comment: This is *way, way* too much code to be in a view. Consider writing a helper method that outputs the correct HTML and just embed a call to that. As a bonus you can write unit tests for these very easily and verify that this code works correctly. Right now it's not clear how this code should be used or what it returns.

Answer (score 3):

The code you show is full of white spaces (at the beginning of each line). Those are printed on the HTML and compacted as one space. Also, when you print a value, it adds an space at the end, you can supress that usign `<%= ... -%>` (note the dash at the end)

https://www.howtobuildsoftware.com/index.php/how-do/Nzr/ruby-on-rails-erb-suppressing-spaces-in-erb-template

Anyway, I would move all that logic to a helper method, that's what helper methods are for.